# Watch app icon in standard Complications not showing

Tags: apple-watch, watchface

[image]

Hi developed and watchkit app and it works fine. The app icon also show in settings and on the watch apps. Thats fine, my only problem is that it isnt shown in the screenshot and on the clock in the watchface. There are just the 2 lines marked in the screenshot. There i can add an image for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. i added black transparent images to the complication